# useRef and useImperativeHandle type error with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code:

```
const Button = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement>((props, ref) => {
  const buttonRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => buttonRef.current);

  return <button ref={buttonRef}>CLICK</ button>
});
```

`buttonRef.current` us underlined and I get this error:

```
Type 'HTMLButtonElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement'
```

I can't seem to understand why...

Comment: I have exactly same issue